# Семантическое значение и связь элементов схемы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со схемой данных на рисунке

ВОПРОСЫ

1. Разница между `Ticket` и `TicketFlies`
2. Можно ли выделять подчинение между таблицами, если да то в каком порядке они подчиняются?
3. Разница `T.TotalAmount`, `TF.Amount`
4. `TF.SeatNumber` и `AC.SeatsNumber`
5. `T.TicketNumber` и `TF.TicketNumber`
6. `BoardingNumber` - номер посадки (имеется ввиду самолета перед полетом или что-то иное?)
7. `FareConditions` - условия тарифа (приведите, пожалуйста, пример)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разобраться в структуре в первую очередь необходимо постараться все перевести. Обычно, чтобы упростить сопровождение разработчики дают осмысленные названия полям и таблицам. Правда, часто используются сокращения и профессиональные термины, поэтому хорошо бы иметь опыт в области.

Даже простой перевод названий таблиц практически отвечает на все ваши вопросы: Полеты (Flights), Билеты (Tickets), Летящие (TicketsFlies), Судна (AirCraft), Аэропорты (Airports).

1. `Tickets` это все проданные билеты, если вы не опоздали на самолет и полетели, то попадаете в таблицу `TicketsFlies`.
2. Подчинение таблиц непростая штука и о порядке говорить сложно. Таблицы могут ссылать по кругу, саму на себя, дважды на одну, короче любые варианты. Опять же при анализе надо найти одинаковые (похожие) столбцы они будут ключами. В представленном случае это поля с постфиксом `ID`, `Code`, `Number` (например, `FlightId`, `AirCraft`, `TicketNumber`).
3. Вот тут я не очень понял (как раз надо знание предметной области) `T.TotalAmount` - это стоимость проданного билета, возможно со всеми накрутками, `TF.Amount` - может реальная стоимость полета.
4. `TF.SeatNumber` - номер места пассажира, и `AC.SeatsNumber` - количество мест в самолете.
5. `T.TicketNumber` и `TF.TicketNumber` эти поля имеют одинаковые значения и как раз обеспечивают подчинение (см. ответ 2).
6. `BoardingNumber` - посадочный номер, номер регистрации билета пассажира.
7. `FareConditions` - условия тарифа это специальная кодировка услуг и их стоимость, которые закладываются авиакомпанией.

Ключи в структуре (PK - Primary key, FK - foreign key), желтое данные.

1. `Flights.FlightId` (PK) -> `TicketsFlies.FlightId` (FK)
2. `Tickets.TicketNumber` (PK) -> `TicketsFlies.TicketNumber` (FK)
3. `AirCraft.AirCraftCode` (PK) -> `Flights.AirCraftCode` (FK)
4. `Airports.AirportCode` (PK) -> `Flights.DepartureAirport` (FK)
5. `Airports.AirportCode` (PK) -> `Flights.ArivalAirport` (FK)
6. `Airports.AirportCode` (PK) -> `Flights.ActualDeparture` (FK)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Только отметьте вопрос плюсом и что дан ответ (стрелка вверх, галочка). Успехов.

Comment: Нет, не правильно. В ответ добавил ключи. Внимательно см. пункт 2. Есть ключи они связывают таблицы. Остальные поля это данные, между ними связи почти нет. В жизни, конечно, есть связь между условиями тарифа и стоимостью билета, но в схеме БД ее нет и искать ее не надо.

Comment: Дополнил еще раз ответ

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все ясно

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста F.FlightId(PK)  TF.FlightId(PK)(FK) связь один к одномy? (Идентификатор полета меняется для каждого пассажира?)

Comment: Связи один ко многим. Один полет много "летящих". У многих пассажиров может быть один идентификатор полета.

Comment: PK для таблицы TicketsFlies состоит из обоих ключевых полей

Comment: Спасибо и уточните пожалуйста если я правильно понимаю FareCondition не зависит от TicketNumber, а только от FlightId, тогда данным достаточно зависеть от одного из атрибутов PK?

Comment: У меня не получается много столбцов в таблице, если следовать правилу для 3нф: 2нф + все не ключевые столбцы взаимно независимы(то есть их надо выносить в отдельную таблицу)  https://habr.com/ru/post/254773/ или здесь надо как-то иначе рассуждать?

Comment: FareCondition не зависит ни от TicketNumber, ни от FlightId. Это характеристика конкретной записи, а у записи есть PK. Все что желтое можно убирать добавлять общее количество записей от этого не измениться. Если у вас есть конкретный вопрос, постарайтесь его сформулировать и задать как новый.

Comment: Вроде FareConditions есть и в AirCraft (на рисунке не видно), и в TicketsFlies. По структуре не понять по смыслу это идинаковые поля или нет. Здесь надо или какое-то описание структуры, или видеть данные.